# How to read "gd:image" element from an Atom feed using ROME

Tags: java, blogger, feed, atom-feed, rome

I'm using ROME library to parse Blogger Atom feed and I need to read an URL of the author thumbnail. How can I do this? The wire feed does not contain this element.

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0'>
    <id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-6916314241990305466</id>
    <updated>2012-03-28T06:24:27.688-07:00</updated>
    <title type='text'>Padgets - City Campaign</title>
    <subtitle type='html'></subtitle>
    <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://padgets-city.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/6916314241990305466/posts/default'/>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://padgets-city.blogspot.com/'/>
    <author>
            <name>PadgetsTest</name>
            <uri>http://www.blogger.com/profile/15823334142528274028</uri>
            <email>noreply@blogger.com</email>
            <!-- How to read following line? -->
            <gd:image rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail' width='32' height='32' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TK6v5Q6uCEI/T3MQ_WqmpoI/AAAAAAAAACM/B-itCET-EMs/s220/b1.jpg'/>
    </author>
    <generator version='7.00' uri='http://www.blogger.com'>Blogger</generator>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue by implementing ROME GData Module. It supports only `image` element, source code can be found at https://github.com/lradziwonowicz/rome-gdata-module-skeleton

I'll try to use  [Abdera](http://abdera.apache.org/) instead of [ROME](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home).

Comment: Good example Lukasz. For others who are interested there is further information about this approach see the [Salmon Run Blog](http://sujitpal.blogspot.tw/2007/10/custom-modules-with-rome.html), this thread on the [ROME email list](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-read-ForeignMarkup-Value-td18762891.html) or this [ROME Tutorial](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4227201).